# Port 80 and 443 not accessible within my AWS instance but works anywhere else

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitnami

I cannot successfully curl or telnet or wget my server ip address or localhost from my AWS instance, but from anywhere else the connection is working.

When I run `sudo netstat -nlp` I get the following:

```
bitnami@ip-172-31-89-32:/opt/bitnami$ sudo netstat -nlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12023/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      616/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:23              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      583/inetd
tcp6       0      0 :::9821                 :::*                    LISTEN      12346/node /opt/bit
tcp6       0      0 :::3110                 :::*                    LISTEN      12322/node /opt/bit
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      11065/httpd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      616/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      6459/node /opt/bitn
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      11065/httpd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           404/dhclient
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           594/chronyd
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                594/chronyd
udp6       0      0 fe80::1011:baff:fe4:546 :::*                                487/dhclient
```

Please help

Have flushed my iptables

```
iptables -L -n -v

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 



# sudo ip6tables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Please help, any idea on how to resolve this. On AWS security group, port 80 and 443 are open.

Security Group inbound rules:

- HTTPS TCP 443 0.0.0.0/0
- HTTP TCP 80 0.0.0.0/0
- HTTP TCP 80 ::/0
- HTTPS TCP 443 ::/0

Security Group outbound rules:

- HTTP TCP 80 0.0.0.0/0
- All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0
- Custom TCP TCP 23 0.0.0.0/0
- HTTP TCP 80 ::/0
- HTTPS TCP 443 ::/0
- HTTPS TCP 443 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: curl: (7) Failed to connect to <public IP> port 443: Connection timed out

Comment: Have also flushed by IPTABLES and yet not working. Here is a result from running iptables -L -n -v.  Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Comment: What is the configuration of the **Security Group** associated with this Amazon EC2 instance? Please show us both the Inbound and Outbound rules.

Comment: Here are the inbound rules

IP version
Type
Protocol
Port range
Source
Description
–
sgr-0df8c9fe2829c7388
IPv4
HTTPS
TCP
443
105.112.62.35/32
 
–
sgr-08022c4eedbace46e
IPv4
HTTP
TCP
80
0.0.0.0/0
–
–
sgr-0a4f619a104e2f6b1
IPv4
HTTP
TCP
80
52.55.239.98/32
–
–sgr-0f44c0abaa0d2fc84
IPv4
HTTPS
TCP
443
52.55.239.98/32
–
 
–
sgr-023f8fb28c1ecb54c
IPv6
HTTP
TCP
80
::/0
–

Comment: @EmiRobert I am having the same issue, did you figure it out in the end?

Comment: Yes, I did. The cause of the problem is the elastic IP address. After disassociating it, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your situation appears to be:

- You are attempting to connect from an Amazon EC2 instance to "itself" via its Public IP address
- The connection is timing-out

When connecting to an EC2 instance via its **public IP address**, the traffic will **exit the VPC**, the Internet Gateway will then perform **reverse NAT** and the traffic will then **re-enter** the VPC. Thus, the Security Group rules will be used. (If you were connecting via `localhost` or the **private IP address**, the traffic would not exit the instance.)

Your Inbound Security Group settings for port 443 are:

- HTTPS TCP 443 105.112.62.35/32
- HTTPS TCP 443 52.55.239.98/32

These rules mean that **connections will *only* be permitted from `105.112.62.35` and `52.55.239.98`**. Your Amazon EC2 instance is *not* using one of these IP addresses, so the Security Group is denying access to the instance.

Comment: Have deleted the following inbound security groups

HTTPS TCP 443 105.112.62.35/32
HTTPS TCP 443 52.55.239.98/32

Thus far, this is what have got

HTTPS TCP 443 0.0.0.0/0
HTTPS TCP 443 ::/0

Comment: Great! Is it working now?

Comment: After removing those security group settings, it's still not working. As a result of this issue, curl is not working for me. Very frustrating

Comment: When I run curl -I 127.0.0.1 ,  this works, but when I replace with my IP ADDRESS, it doesn't

Comment: @hey man, have you fixed this yet? I am currently exp this issue??